# Bootstrap Datepicker beforeShowDay: function (date) date is undefined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm tying to diable some of the dates in a datepicker. But the 'date' is always undefined in disableDates. Is there something I,m missing? I'm new to javascript so maybe there is something that i don't quite understand yet.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {},
            $el = $(element);


        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        $el.datepicker(options);
        $el.datepicker('setEndDate', new Date);
        $el.datepicker('beforeShowDay', disableDates());

        function disableDates(date) {
            self.getDates();
            var showDate = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < self.dates.length; i++) {
                if (date.toDateString() === new Date(self.dates()[i].ReportingDate).toDateString()) {
                    showDate = false;
                }
            }
            return [showDate, ""];

        }

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $el.datepicker("destroy");
        });
    },

    update: function (element) {
        var value = self.ReportingDate(),
            $el = $(element),
            current = $el.datepicker("getDate");
        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $el.datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//initialize datepicker with some optional options
$.extend(options, {
    beforeShowDay: disableDates
})
$el.datepicker(options);
$el.datepicker('setEndDate', new Date);
```

Comment: When I try that it never enters the function.

Comment: @LadyBug the function will get called when you open the datepicker

Comment: @LadyBug also there is no method called `setEndDate` what are you trying to do with it

Comment: @LadyBug a simple jQuery sample will look like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mJ4F6/1/

Comment: The setEndDate disables all dates after today. This one works fine. But the beforShowDay is never called even if i open the datepicker.

Comment: @LadyBug jQuery and jQuery UI versions used?

Comment: @LadyBug are you using jQuery UI datepicker or bootstrap datepicker

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v2.0.2 and bootstrap-transition.js v2.3.2

Comment: with bootstrap-datepicker.js